# How to read a tekst file during runtime

Tags: go

Hi I have a program where I want to read files relative to the binary installed in the bin folder.
I have looked at using:

```
filepath.Abs
os.Getwd()
```

But this only gives me the folder beneath "src" during.

Eventually I will use:

```
os.Open(abspath)
```

How do you read files during runtime?

Comment: What is “the bin folder?”

Comment: `runtime.Caller()` is about traversing the call stack of the invoking function and hence has nothing to do with paths and folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had already seen the osext, but now that dyoo mentioned it - I went for it. And it works.

https://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext

Thanks